# React Native connecting to MongoLab

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently creating a React Native application for iOS that will have to query a DB, I have decided to use [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/). When looking at MongoLab's docs, they recommend to use the MongoDB Drivers when connecting.

I assume that using either [MongoLab NodeJS Driver](https://github.com/mongolab/mongodb-driver-examples/blob/master/nodejs/nodeSimpleExample.js) or [MongoLab Mongoose Driver](https://github.com/mongolab/mongodb-driver-examples/blob/master/nodejs/mongooseSimpleExample.js) is the best method for React Native, however there is a real lack of documentation online for connecting MongoDBs and React Native.

One concern is that ReactNative does not 'allow' npm packages to work as they would in a normal NodeJS project.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I doubt that drivers intended for the Node.js infrastructure will work in JavascriptCore on iOS. If you want to avoid running your own backend you should consider on of the Backend-as-a-Service providers like Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/). If you are not set on MongoDb you could also consider CouchDb which has a REST API. There is also the PouchDb (http://pouchdb.com/) project that is a CouchDb client in the browser.